# Api post request. What is wrong with my script?

Tags: arrays, json, api

I am trying to create a post request for an energy company but I keep getting a failed message. Can you guys help me out and let me know if this looks off? Thanks

```
 $fields = array("firstName"=>"Test",
"lastName"=>"Tester",
"dob"=>"01/01/1980",
"socialSecurity"=>"123456789",
"phoneAreaCode"=>"111",
"phoneExchange"=>"111",
"phoneLine"=>"1111",
"email"=>"test@test.com",
"serviceAddress"=>array(
"line1"=>"123 Main ST",
"line2"=>"Unit 123",
"city"=>"Decatur",
"state"=>"GA",
"zip"=>"30031"
),
"mailingAddress"=>array(
"line1"=>"7001 SW 24th AVE",
"city"=>"Gainesville",
"state"=>"FL",
"zip"=>"32607"
),
"utilityName"=>"AGLC",
"ratePlanName"=>"6 mo Fixed",
"requestedService"=>"SWITCH",
"language"=>"ENGLISH",
"referredBy"=>"Test Referral",
"marketerName"=>"Test Marketer");

$str_data = json_encode($fields);
$uri = "https://sandbox.infiniteenergy.com/api/enrollments";

$response = \Httpful\Request::post($uri)
->addHeaders(array(
'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 
'Accept' => 'application/json',
'AccessKeyId' => 'a13bd2fa-f959-4f91-b238-9757a3172945'
))
->body($str_data)
->sendsJson()
->send();
```

I keep getting {"success":false,"message":"Method not allowed","data":null}

I am about to pull my hair out I need this fixed today.

Answer (score 0):

Method Not allowed is triggered when your API could be hit with post and you are hit it with get request, vice versa

so if your method is HttpGet you have to make an htttp get request and if it is post you have to make and httpPost request

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you show me what I would need to change in my script?

Comment: what is this language ? you didn't mention the program language you use
I answered you in general why this problem is happening

Comment: Quick question. I am using Httpful. Sp post and get would be used no?

Comment: I am using php for this script.

Comment: change your api to be REQUEST

Comment: What do you mean change my api to be REQUEST?

Comment: When you build an API , you will tell it how to access the this api weather
if it is a post|get|PUT|Delete|request and so on 

all of them should be the same if you are hitting post then the api should be post if get then your api should be get
however your API should be request in order to accept all Methods

Comment: use \Httpful\Request;

$uri = "https://sandbox.infiniteenergy.com/api/enrollments";

$response = \Httpful\Request::post($uri)
        ->addHeaders(array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',              
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'AccessKeyId' => 'a13bd2fa-f959-4f91-b238-9757a3172945'
    ))
 ->body($str_data)
    ->sendsJson()
    ->send();

 
 
echo $response;

Comment: It seems to be okay i'm not a php developer but as i see if your code is working above this will be enough